# IE 11/12 border-radius 1px bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

I've just found out that IE 11 & 12 can't handle border-radius properly. Sometimes (not always, what is extra wierd) there is a 1px gap between the border element and the next element like here

http://www.leukewereld.be/wp/

When I drop the border-radius all is fine.
Anybody knows a solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a bug which has been reported in IE11. You can refer [IE 11 Div With "border-radius" Bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a7808c7d-0178-4b10-b8b1-fbb06dd6ee28/ie-11-div-with-borderradius-bug) which contains the solution and the discussion on the same.

Comment: @MDC - I agree.  Maybe if you post a message into that thread and ask IECustomizer MVP to clarify his official **Answer**, he'll explain his secret to fixing it.  (as illustrated).  He posts in that msdn forum practically daily.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same bug on my current project. Not only with border-radiuses (as disabling those did not always make a difference) but with box-shadows as well. Using certain line-height values in the affected area seemed to work, but necessitated ugly workarounds to keep the layout as intended...

A good solution in my case, and perhaps for many others, is to use an **overflow:hidden** wrapper. (Luckily I happened to need one of those anyway.)

I forgot where I originally found that suggestion but kudos to the person who came up with it! :)